# Microsoft Outlook 365 (Windows Only) ADD-IN ERROR

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, appsource

I have been consistently receiving this [ADD-IN ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awbFW.png) which states: "ADD-IN ERROR This add-in could not be started. Close this dialog to ignore the problem or click "Restart" to try again."

This happens from the following very specific chain of events:

1. When I open the new email/compose screen
2. As soon as the screen loads I click on the ADD-IN and click a button on the toolbar associated with the ADD-IN

Microsoft Edge Dev Tools (not OWA) do not catch this error because essentially the new email/compose view is not able to be picked up even when I spam refresh. I can view it in Dev Tools only when I don't receive this error.

Outlook logs are hard to read, but I have found one error that might be a smoking gun: Unable to open volatile key. (0x80070005). This however doesn't have much documentation surrounding it.

Would anyone have insight on this issue, Thanks in advance!!

EDIT: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): : {"status":"failed","error":{"name":"MissingExtendedPermissionsForAPIError","message":"Extended Permission missing for the API call.","code":9047}}

This seems to fire in reference to a manifest addition AppendOnSend Here are the docs on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/extendedpermissions Why would this error out when clicking on a ribbon icon?

EDIT 2: Trying to validate the XML used in the addin I receive:

> **has invalid child element 'ExtendedPermissions'**

even though I am following the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/extendedpermission

Comment: The pic is pretty generic, if I see that error, I first go to Fiddler/network tools to see if there is any issue with retrieving files or network requests when the view is loading. When did this start happening?  I have had issues in the past trying to set breakpoints and debug, and sometimes have to end all browser processes and start again to start debugging again.  I haven't tried debugging with Edge Chromium but my 'legacy' Edge is generally the most painful debugging environment.  I'd rather use IE or Chrome which leads me to ask, does this issue ONLY occur on Edge?

Comment: @BrianClink Thanks for the response. It may seem generic however there are subtleties in all of the ADD-IN ERRORS. 500/504's produce a "A problem occurred while trying to reach this add-in". I would love to go through and set break points however it is only a Desktop App and does not occur in OWA. Therefore is not related to Edge or browsers etc.. So the debugging here is painful, I can only look at OutlookLogs which are difficult to read. To clarify Edge Tools can be used for the desktop app.

Comment: Could you tell us your Office build and Windows version? This can help confirm whether the Office you have is using a web control based on Edge vs IE. More details here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-edge-webview-for-office-add-ins/

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT sure the current Outlook Version is 2004 (Build 12730.20206) the Windows Version I am running is 2004 (OS Build 19619.1000). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Those builds mean that in the Desktop App it will be using the Edge Browser to render your add-in. Do you get this error 100% of the time? or less? Do other users get it as well? Do you get this error with other add-ins installed from the store? Or only some add-ins? or just yours? has the add-in ever worked?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT sorry for the late response! I can create the error 50% of the time. Users with a slower machine can recreate it 100% of the time. (Essentially it occurs during the window when the add-in is loading). I do not get this error from other add-ins in the store. If you know of any that have buttons associated to the add-in in the taskbar then I could try and recreate it with a different add-in (please let me know if that makes sense). And yes the add-in works great, but I can break it in the loading process as stated above.

Comment: If this is not occurring in other add-ins, then I would guess there may be a problem connecting to your add-in server. (sorry I'm not sure what you mean by buttons associated to the add-in in the taskbar? Do you mean ribbon?) Does the add-in load if you hit retry? Brian's suggestion of running fiddler, and seeing the results of trying to load your html file from your source location, (as well as the other files) may help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Another thing to do, is to click on the smily and send us feedback. You will have the option to attach logs. Once you do that, you can provide the logs to us.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Yes clicking a *ribbon item* associated with the add-in. And I would love to run dev tools except this error essentially breaks that service (when it errors out the tool can no longer find the compose window). And sure I will go ahead and send the error logs, thx :)

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I have sent the logs/more information.

Comment: @wsoccorsi, sorry I think I miscommunicated. Thanks for sending the logs, but can you manually put them somewhere accessible so that we can download them directly and take a look?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT sure is there an email I can reach you at?

Comment: We generally don't share our e-mail addresses publicly. Can you place it on OneDrive Pro?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT So I went ahead and attached the logs to another feedback ticket, please lmk if thats acceptable. I just wouldn't want a public drive here for privacy reasons.

Comment: Thanks @wsoccorsi. That's the best way to get the logs to us.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Great! I also just attached an edit for this error which I think will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here happened to be with using the Microsoft Preview API. The Add-In will throw this error when you accidentally have AppendOnSend enabled while using a manifest that does not have Preview.